# GET /favicon.icon 404 error in ngrok

Tags: http-status-code-404, favicon, ngrok

On running ngrok and going to the suggested url, i get 
`GET /favicon.icon 404 error` in ngrok.

In which folder does ngrok search for the favicon.ico file ?

How do i fix this ?

Very new to ngrok. Do help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar problem with URIs from ngrok being served as 404s.

I have a local Apache, PHP and MySQL stack setup on macOS using `*.dev` domains.

So in my case, I needed to set the [`host-header`](https://ngrok.com/docs#host-header) option in ngrok to match the hostname of the virtual host Apache was configured for.

Here's the relevant part of my Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.dev
    ServerAlias www.example.dev
    ...
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

The necessary ngrok arguments to tunnel requests to my private development domain were:

`$ ngrok http example.dev:80 -host-header=example.dev`

Comment: Works form me with IIS and localhost (https://localhost/api  etc): 

          PS: .\ngrok.exe http https://localhost  -host-header=localhost

Answer (score 2):

What ngrok do is,make **tunnels to localhost**.That allows you tunnel requests from Internet to your local machine.

You can see following details after running : **ngrok http 8888**

Tunnel Status

```
online                                            
Version                       2.0.19/2.0.19                                     
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040 
Forwarding                    http://299954c1.ngrok.io -> localhost:8888
```

Now all the data intended for 'http://299954c1.ngrok.io' url which is publically accessible will come to your local machine at port 8888

You need to have some **server** running on your local machine at port **8888** which can serve '**favicon.icon**' static file

If you are able to get icon by hitting : **localhost:8888/favicon.icon** in your browser, You will surely get it from **http://299954c1.ngrok.io/favicon.icon**